# Custom Video Streaming Spring mvc

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc

I am developing an learning management system web Application in spring mvc which provides video tutorial to users.

For managing the video content, I would like to stream and buffer video without any third party application and want to implement some custom control over the video player.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: so what is the issue? Spring MVC is a request - response model and has nothing to do with video streaming.

Comment: There is an availability to flush stream of bytes to the video. but need control over seeking and pausing the video.

Comment: Is that something you trying to do with html5 front end / scripting or Java back end ? You  need to tell as what you tried and where you are stuck?This is not a place to get ready made solutions. If your question has appropriate information, would be easy for somebody else to answer too.

Comment: For a try i have tried some media source extension but it doesn't buffer video in some browsers like firefox and some file type is not working. so i want to do in a custom manner by flushing the data bytes to video tag in html5. But control over the video element like seeking is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Spring Content](https://paulcwarren.github.io/spring-content/).  This Spring project allows you to create REST endpoints that can manage content including videos very easily.  It is based on similar programming paradigms to Spring Data and in fact can be paired with Spring Data to allow you to store and search metadata for you video content too.  From you problem description it sounds like it would help a lot with the video in your learning management system .